# Multiplying Elements in a List in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a list

```
alist = [6, 6, 6, 3, 1]
```

And I want to multiply every element in the list by 4 and return

```
alist = [24, 24, 24, 12, 4]
```

My current approach is to iterate through the list and multiply each element, just like:

```
for i in range(len(alist)):
    alist[i] = alist[i] * 4
```

Which is very inefficient, because once the first 6*4 is calculated, it's redundant to calculate it again for the second and third sixes. When I'm doing contest problems, it always exceeds the time limit once the numbers get large.

Is there a way to do the same multiplication process that *doesn't* calculate the same thing over and over again?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, could this be what you are looking for:

```
alist = [6,6,6,3,1]

adict = {a: a*4 for a in set(alist)}

alist = [adict[a] for a in alist]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what this is doing, i.e. that `set` means you're only processing unique entries and the dictionary provides a mapping of inputs to outputs. Also note that this requires an `O(n)` scan of `alist` to build the set.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a memoized function, which means that it can look up old results. For multiplication this might not help much, but for more complicated operations it can improve performance a lot.

```
cached_results = {}
def calc(a, b):
    if (a, b) not in cached_results:
        cached_results[(a, b)] = a*b
    else:
        print "already calculated value for (%s, %s)" % (a, b)
    return cached_results[(a, b)]

alist = [6, 6, 6, 3, 1]
print [calc(x, 4) for x in alist]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if multiplication is what you would like to optimize here. Instead, use list comprehension:

```
alist = [n * 4 for n in alist]
```

Or, use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
alist = map(lambda n: n * 4, alist)
```

It is also recommended in [Python Wiki on Performance Tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops):

> List comprehensions were added to Python in version 2.0 as well. They provide a syntactically more compact and more efficient way of writing the above for loop.

Comment: That would be more efficient than `append`ing to a new list, but the OP *isn't creating a new list*, they're mutating the old one.

Comment: yes, and that's why I assigned it to the same variable. Is that not good enough?

Comment: You could do `alist[:] = [...]`, but my point is that showing them a more efficient way to build a new list may not help them when *that isn't what they're doing*. Have you tested the list comprehension against their formulation? How does this avoid the repeated calculation they're asking about?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes you are right. My answer just educate the OP about the usage of list comprehension instead of optimizing the multiplication problem. So this just solves half the problem.

Comment: `alist = [n * 4 for n in alist]` is certainly faster than `alist[:] = [n * 4 for n in alist]` since the 1st one simply binds the new list object to the `alist` name, replacing the old object, whereas the 2nd one has to copy the new list to the old object (although that copy operation happens at C speed so it's faster than doing an item by item copy with explicit Python code). FWIW, the `map` version is noticeably slower (given a large enough list) because it performs a Python function call on each item: Python function calls are relatively slow compared to calling functions implemented in C.

Answer (score 1):

For longer lists a numpy array could be a better choice:

```
anarray = numpy.array([6,6,6,3,1])
anarray *= 4
```

I am quite sure that any kind of lookup to make sure that you don't do the same multiplication twice takes longer than actually doing the multiplication once more.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like simple in list comprehension.

`alist = [6,6,6,3,1]
result = [x*4 for x in alist]
print result`

Answer (score 0):

Good question use the inbuilt method **append()** in the python
suppose in your case it is like Given list is like 
aList = [6, 6, 6, 3, 1]
then use

---

b=List()

---

for i in alist:

---

```
    b.append(i*4)
```

print b #new list will take the result